# Sentiment positive attitude in Twitter API gives exception

Tags: c#, api, twitter

I'm using [Twitter search](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) API. My code is working well until I need to add negative attitude (sentiment if you search "flight :(" on Twitter API above link). I want to add it in my search; how can I do that?

Here is my working code:

```
var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", oauth_version=\"{6}\"";
 var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
); 
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false; 
resource_url += "?" + string.Join("&", RequestParameters.Select(p => string.Format("{0}={1}", p.Key, Uri.EscapeDataString(p.Value))));
System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
using (var response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{return reader.ReadToEnd();}
}
```

url

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&include_entities=0&lang=en&q="Manpower"+:)&max_id=
```

If I remove my `:(` from my URL then everything goes fine and when I add it then it gives:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

and I'm encoding using Uri.EscapeDataString class. I have also tried adding plus sign "**+**:("

Comment: i didnt find any answer and now im using tweetinvi C#